# Get Topics ordered by recent Entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Suppose that I have models:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to create a queryset that returns Topics which has Entries whose creation date is in last 24 hours. Topics should be ordered so that the first topic has the latest Entry.

I tried this with Postgres, but the ordering is lost:

```
Topic.objects.filter(entry_set__date_created__gte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24))\
               .order_by('entry_set__topic', '-entry_set__date_created').distinct('entry_set__topic')
```

I found [a solution to a similar problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b787d3/1) but it is written in raw sql, and I couldn't convert it to django-orm.

Update:

So here is a working solution that achieves what I want in 2 querysets (I'm looking for a solution that can achieve this in one queryset):

```
desired_date = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
distinct_ids = Topic.objects.filter(entries__date_created__gte=desired_date).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)
ordered_qs = Topic.objects.filter(id__in=distinct_ids).annotate(lts=Max("entries__date_created")).order_by('-lts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db.models import Max

latest_entry_time = dict(last_entry_dt=Max('entries__date_created'))
last_24_hour_filter = dict(entries__date_created__gte=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24))

result = Topic.objects.annotate(**latest_entry_time).filter(**last_24_hour_filter).order_by('-last_entry_dt')
```

---

### Explanation

1. **`latest_entry_time`** : Used to annotate the ***latest `date_created`*** value into ***each `Topic` object***
2. **`last_24_hour_filter`** : used to filter out the **Entry** instances
3. **`.order_by('-last_entry_dt')`** : Since we do have the ***annotated field*** (see *explanation 1*), we can use that here.
   Hope its clear !!

Comment: Great, I never thought it would be that easy! But I have a question: is prev_24_hour_topics = Topic.objects.annotate(last_entry_dt=Max('entries__date_created')).filter(
        entries__date_created__gte=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)).order_by('-last_entry_dt') any different?

Comment: No, I mean did you use dictionary unpacking for just readability or is there any specific function of it?

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

```
desired_date = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
topics=Entry.objects.filter(date_created__gte=desired_date).order_by('date_created').values_list('topic', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: removing the first argument creates duplicates. I thought of distinct to remove these but distinct argument needs to be the same as the first argument.

Comment: Try reordering your modifiers. Do Topic.objects.filter(entry_set__date_created__gte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)).distinct('entry_set__topic').order_by('-entry_set__date_created')

Comment: It yields the same result, they are probably converted to same SQL at the back. And as far as I know, there is no way to make distinct objects ordered.

Comment: Use two separate queries. With an intermediary id list. I updated my initial comment.

Comment: In the ordered_qs the use of entry_set__date_created creates objects from other topics (it probably considers all the entries), but it can be solved: "Topic.objects.filter(id__in=distinct_ids).annotate(lts=Max("entries__date_created")).order_by('-lts')". However that doesn't answer my question as I need only one query

Comment: Let's try starting with the Entry model instead then.

Answer (score 0):

Topics can be ordered so that the first topic has the latest Entry by giving a model metadata.

Here `-date_added` will sort your topic as your wish. Give your model metadata by using an inner **class Meta**, like so:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Model metadata is “anything that’s not a field”, such as ordering options (`ordering`), database table name (`db_table`), or human-readable singular and plural names (`verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`). None are required, and adding class Meta to a model is completely optional.

This [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/) explains all the possible metadata options that you can give your model

Comment: This will not work because the metadata does not consider the creation date of entries,instead; it considers the topic creation date. Adding the metadata option to Entry model has the same effect of order_by.